# how can I set-attribute to input Element

Tags: javascript

```
var 
nInput = document.createElement('input'),

clsinput = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

clsinput.setAttribute('class','new');
```

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns a collection of element, do you want the first?

Comment: you can use nInput directly. `nInput.setAttribute('class', 'new').` document.getElementsByTagName returns an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var nInput = document.createElement('input'),

clsinput = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

clsinput.setAttribute('class','new');
```

getElementsByTagName returns an array. You are trying to set an attribute to that returned array. You have to iterate that array and set attribute.

Oh wait, you don't need that middle line at all.  You created an input element in first line, just use that and set attribute to it

```
var nInput = document.createElement('input'),
nInput.setAttribute('class','new');
```